# Convergent series with general term greater than the one of a divergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm curious is there, a convergent series with general term $a_n$ where $a_n > b_n$ ?

Considering that the series with general term $b_n$ diverges . My intuition says there isn't, but I can't think of a way to prove it .

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

If $b_n$ is positive then the answer is NO and the proof is easy using the partial sum. Otherwise a counterexample is : take for example $b_n=-\frac1n$ and $a_n=0$